# Convert string to lower case except all metacharacters

Tags: java, regex, string, lowercase

I want to convert a a String (basically a regex itself) to a lowercase but I want to exclude metacharacters from getting converted.

e.g. :

If I do

```
String x = "[\\s\\S]*Test Message Indicator: (.*)[\\s\\S]*";
x = x.toLowerCase();
```

It will also convert a capital `S` in `\\S` to `s` which will change the meaning of a regex.

I want to avoid that.

Final regex should like `[\\s\\S]*test message indicator: (.*)[\\s\\S]*`.

Is there any way I can do this easily?

Comment: Can't you just use it with case sensitivity off?

Comment: not with a string function. you'd need one that's regex-aware, which probably isn't going to happen. some lib that tokenizes the regex and lets you deal with only "text nodes" in the regex would do, but finding such a thing would be off-topic for this site.

Comment: I'd suggest not inlining regex into your values if the entire value is not meant to be seen as a regex. Keep the concerns seperated. Otherwise, you're gonna have to write your own parser to break it down and extract the value, which would be quite hard without some kind of template

Comment: You should look at http://xyproblem.info/ and think about the actual problem that you're trying to solve. There's probably a better way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Please show how the final result (the modified regex) will be used. I suspect there's a better way. I also suspect what you're trying to do is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a placeholder (that you know will not be in the input String) to swap in and out the uppercase predefined character classes of the regular expression. For example, replace with unicode values `00A0`, `00A1`, `00A2` for `\S`, `\D`, and `\W` respectively (or whichever char values you anticipate to never see), lower case the string, and back-replace with the special chars:

```
String x = "[\\s\\S]*Test Message Indicator: (.*)[\\s\\S]*";
x = x.replaceAll("\\\\S", "\u00A0").replaceAll("\\\\D","\u00A1").replaceAll("\\\\W","\u00A2");;
x = x.toLowerCase();
x = x.replaceAll("\u00A0", "\\\\S").replaceAll("\u00A1","\\\\D").replaceAll("\u00A2","\\\\W");;
System.out.println(x);
```

Granted this only accounts for a few common uppercase character classes (and could be inefficient depending upon context) - you would need to consult the the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) if the regular expressions are complex and you need to account for all possible uppercase regular expression values.

Comment: That might work, but it needs to account for all possible regex metacharacters. Such as [described here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Comment: @gregn3 excellent point. I've updated the answer to be more explicit

Comment: Yes if the OP intends to use it more than once, it should be a general solution.